# Edit post pages with PHP and CSS in Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, posts

I would edit the pages of posts (eg: http://example.com/author/wordpress_post) with PHP and CSS. How can I do it? Is there already a default PHP file for posts that I can modify?

Comment: Please add more information what you like to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to read up on WordPress' [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Posts, by default, use the `single.php` file, located in the theme directory. Note if you have a Parent Theme and an active Child Theme, your child theme may not have a `single.php` file. You can, however, copy the `single.php` file from the parent to the child and modify it from there, knowing that if the parent theme structure changes, your child theme *may* need to accommodate.

If your theme uses a different structure, you can always modify the single post functionality with the [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) function in your `functions.php` file. If you just want to edit post titles, you could put this code in `functions.php`

```
function my_title_filter( $title, $post_id = null ) {
    if( is_single() ){
        // Only modifies Post titles, no other titles.
        $title = 'Add This Before Post Titles '. $title;   
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_title_filter' );
```

For CSS, just, well, use CSS. Open up `style.css` or the customizer and go to "Additional CSS" and make the changes you want. On single posts, the body (should) have the class `single-post` so you can filter out CSS changes only for posts by prefixing your selectors with that.

```
/* Make paragraphs a light blue, but only on single posts */
.single-post p {
    color: #0095EE;
}
```